# Itext converting PDF to PDF-A-1A, Vera PDF validation

Tags: java, validation, pdf, itext

Am using Itext 5.5.13.1 version and am trying to convert PDF to PDF-A-1A. Test passed but my validation failure, for validation am using VERA PDF validation, error is this one:

**PDF validation failure, errors: RuleId [specification=ISO 19005-1:2005, clause=6.4, testNumber=2] :: failed :: An XObject dictionary shall not contain the SMask key ::**

Does anyone know this solution? In my PDF am using forms and checkboxes, and some images.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not aware of *Itext 5.5.13.1* having the feature *to convert PDF to PDF-A-1A*. I assume your code essentially only copies your original PDF and adds a PDF/A marker without actually changing contents to match PDF/A requirements. As an aside, fully automatic PDF-to-PDF/A-nA is questionable in general as for proper tagging the *intention* of text must be known...

Comment: Do you know any example how can i solve that?

Comment: No. As said above: I'm not aware of Itext 5.5.13.1 having the feature to convert PDF to PDF-A-1A.

Comment: Does this dependecy exists in itext 7? 

 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: That dependency clearly is an iText 5.5.13.1 dependency.